# Migrate address field

Tags: 8, migrations

I am currently searching for a example to migrate data into an address field in Drupal 8 without any luck for now.

Has someone a hint for me on how to map the fields?

I tried the following:

my.migrate.yml file:

```
'field_date_address/address_line1': date_tmp_address_address_line1
'field_date_address/locality': date_tmp_address_locality
'field_date_address/postal_code': date_tmp_address_postal_code
```

Callback:

```
$row->setSourceProperty('date_tmp_address_address_line1', 'Teststreet 18');
$row->setSourceProperty('date_tmp_address_locality', 'Test locallity');
$row->setSourceProperty('date_tmp_address_postal_code', '12345');
```

Comment: I was able to solve it :-) This helped me:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2594631#comment-11322879 It is important to map all addressfield subfields, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I do migrate from json to drupal 8, hope this will help.

In the .yml I call the field on a single value :

```
id: my_id_migrate
label: My Label
migration_group: MyGroup
migration_dependencies: {}

source:
  plugin: json_source
  path: URL_TO_JSON_FILE
  headers:
    Accept: 'application/json'
  identifier: id
  identifierDepth: 0
  fields:
    - id
    - title
    - address

destination:
  plugin: entity:node

process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: my_node_type

  title: title

  field_geolocation : geolocation
  field_address : address
```

And 'address' is an array of all subfields :

.json source :

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"Title 1",
      "address":{
         "address_line1":"adress 1",
         "address_line2":"",
         "postal_code":"11111",
         "locality":"City of lights",
         "country_code":"DE"
      },
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Title 2",
      "address":{
         "address_line1":"adress 1 of number2",
         "address_line2":"",
         "postal_code":"11111",
         "locality":"City of lights",
         "country-code":"DE"
      },
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "title":"Title 3",
      "address":{
         "address_line1":"adress 1 of number3",
         "address_line2":"",
         "postal_code":"11111",
         "locality":"City of lights",
         "country_code":"DE"
      },
   }
]
```

Works with all subfields, and works fine for all fields in drupal 8 that have subfields (like geolocation fields for example)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with a user [profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile) migration (not Drupal user account).

`Adress` is an array of subfields.  You can check in database all the possible subfields because i don’t use all of them (ex :  `field_profile_address_family_name`)

.yml file :

```
field_profile_address/country_code:
     plugin: default_value
     default_value: FR
   field_profile_address/langcode:
     plugin: default_value
     default_value: fr
   field_profile_address/address_line1: adresse1
   field_profile_address/address_line1: adresse2
   field_profile_address/locality: ville

   field_profile_address/postal_code: code_postal
```